# How do I do bind list of custom objects to ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I bind a list of custom objects to a combobox? This is what I have currently:

```
            this.classCmbo.DataSource = _viewModel.Coarses;
            this.classCmbo.DisplayMember = "Name";
            this.classCmbo.ValueMember = "Id";
```

I what "Name" to be displayed but I want the "Id" to be the value associated with a selection. How do you do this in winforms?

Here is the Coarse obj:

```
 public class Coarse
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
        public virtual string Name { get;  set; }
    }
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 11):

you can try like this.....

```
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public Country(string _name)
    {
        Cities = new List<City>();
        Name = _name;
    }
}

List<Country> countries = new List<Country> { new Country("UK"), 
                                     new Country("Australia"), 
                                     new Country("France") };

bindingSource1.DataSource = countries;

comboBox1.DataSource = bindingSource1.DataSource;

comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Name";
```

I hope it will helps you...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what your `_viewModel.Coarses` is but try this?

```
this.classCmbo.DataSource = _viewModel.Coarses;
this.classCmbo.DisplayMember = _viewModel.Coarses.Name;
this.classCmbo.ValueMember = _viewModel.Coarses.Id;
```

or just

```
this.classCmbo.DataSource = _viewModel.Coarses;
this.classCmbo.DisplayMember = Coarses.Name;
this.classCmbo.ValueMember = Coarses.Id;
```

Comment: Thank you but _viewModel.Coarse is a collection of Coarse.. ie IList<Coarse> Therefore _viewModel.Coarses.Name does not make sense "Coarses" is a collection of type "Coarse"

Comment: Did you try it as just `Coarses.Name`, or maybe `classCmbo.DataSource.Name`? Sorry I haven't had any issues with this, but I've only done it in WPF so not sure how it translates back to WinForms :(

Answer (score 1):

You can typically use ComboBoxItem.Tag for this sort of thing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx

Comment: Thanks.. I should have mentioned this is a WinForm application not WPF

Comment: Oh I see, I missed that, sorry D:

ComboBoxes in winforms just use a collection of objects for its items. They can be absolutely anything. The text shown in the ComboBox for that item is whatever it's ToString() returns.

What I would do is write a class with all the information you need stored as properties (or use one you've already written) and include a Text property for what you want to display in the ComboBox. Then it's just a matter of overriding the ToString() method to return the contents of your Text property. Then you can add it using myComboBox.Items.Add(myCustomObject);