# Can you enter data from a List to a combobox

Tags: c#

I have created a list within a class, following the same sort of lines as

```
public class Data
{
    private int num;
    private string text;


    public Data()
    {
    }

    public int Num
    {
        get { return num; }
        set { num = value; }
    }
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { text = value; }
    }


   static private List<Data> DataList = new List<Data>();

    static  public List<Data> GetList()
    {
        return DataList
    }
```

and I bring up the list in other classes using

```
List<Data> DataList = Data.GetList();
```

- does getting the list in another class allow you to add items to it?
- and how would I add the items to a combobox?

EDIT: i am trying

```
    LstList.Items.Add(DataList.Any(item => item.Num));
```

but I get the errors "cannot implicitly convert type int to bool"
and "A local variable named "Data" cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning  to "Data""

EDIT: I have tried using .DataSource, but apparently it doesn't exist?

Comment: Robotic English... Please write a more understandable text.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking at adding new items to the static List in the above code from some other Class. If so, then no you cant do it. If you want to do it, expose a method called

```
public static void SetList(Data item_)
{
DataList.Add(item_);
}
```

Or make the List Public to be exposed to other classes

To your second point one assigns the data source of the comboBox to the List.

```
comboBox.DataSource= DataList;
```

This is an additional link that would help
[How do I do bind list of custom objects to ComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024142/how-do-i-do-bind-list-of-custom-objects-to-combobox)

Comment: so changing static private List<Data> DataList = new List<Data>(); to static public List<Data> DataList = new List<Data>(); should solve my first problem?

Comment: Ideally Yes!! It should also solve your second Issue since, you get to directly bind it to dataSource.

Comment: I can't seem to use dataSource, systems can't seem to find the definition :/

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the list as a `DataSource`

```
 comboboxName.DataSource = Data.GetList();
 comboboxName.ValueMember = "Num";
 comboboxName.DisplayMember = "Text";
```

Answer (score 0):

loop each data class from DataList and add the num property to the ListView Control

```
foreach(Data aData in DataList)
{
    LstList.Items.Add(aData.Num.ToString()));
}
```